# Static cast to avoid IDE warnings?

Tags: c++

I am using Clion and I frequently get `Parameter type mismatch` warnings.  For instance in the following:

```
std::default_random_engine random_engine(time(0));
```

I get `Parameter type mismatch: Using 'unsigned long' for signed values of type 'time_t'`

The only way I know of to avoid this warning is to use a static cast such as:

```
std::default_random_engine random_engine(static_cast<unsigned long>(time(0)))
```

This cast can be done automatically.  It is not necessary for my program to compile.

However, are there any performance costs (or other reasons why) I should avoid using static casts when a parameter can be automatically converted?

Comment: The cast will happen either way. Better to do it explicitly, hence informing both the compiler as well as future code readers.

Comment: A hint specifically for the example code you posted: don't use the time as a random seed. It's better to pull a single random number from `std::random_device` and use it as a seed for the actual engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a general chain of principle, that should contain an answer :-)

1. Any Build must be completely Warning Free. (`/WX` or whatever you have)
2. You should enable as many warnings as possible.
3. You should avoid C-style casts, because they *will* come back to bite you.
4. A `static_cast` does never incur more performance cost than an implicit cast would. (Which is often `0`.)
5. When possible, use the exact type. (e.g. use integer or floating point literal type postfixes)
6. When you can't match the exact type, because two functions (or ...) expect different, but compatible types, and if the implicit conversion triggers a waring, use `static_cast`
7. (!) If the implicit conversion triggers a warning, this is most likely because the conversion is *lossy* or otherwise problematic in some edge cases.
8. Consider writing shim functions (possibly with additional run time checking) for these lossy casts.

Comment: In this case the cast isn’t lossy, just “otherwise problematic”; specifically, if you run this code requiring C++11 features and written in 2018 at a time earlier than 1970, you will get a different set of pseudorandom numbers than you might expect. Sure, these are nice general principles, but 7 and 8 don’t really apply here.